# Traverse variable outside of forEach

Tags: angularjs

I have this `forEach` function,

```
angular.forEach(response, function(item){
  if (item.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
    $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
    var youtubeString = $scope.youtubeTrailer.join();
  }
  console.log (youtubeString)
});
```

This gets all the `key` values from a response and pushes them into a scope called `youtubeTrailer`. Then I use `join()` to convert the array into a string and place the string in a variable.

Now I want to use the variable `youtubeString` inside a create function,

```
createMovie.create({
  release_date:    $scope.movieListID.release_date,
  youtube_trailer: youtubeString,
  imdb_rating:     $scope.movieImdbRating.imdbRating,
  title:           $scope.movieListID.original_title,
  image:           $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
  movie_id:        $scope.movieListID.id
}).then(init);
```

But since the create function is outside of the `forEach` function (otherwise it would do the create action for every value in the forEach`) I get an`youtubeString is undefined`.

So how can I acces the variable `youtubeString` from the `forEach` inside the create function?

Comment: call the create-function inside the forEach? if you want to create a movie for each response

Comment: That's not going to work. The forEach loops through each `key` result from a movie. So 1 movie can have 5 key results (which are the youtube links). So if I put the create inside the forEach it would also do the create function for the same movie 5 times.

Comment: Well, I have a real hard time understanding what it is you are trying to achieve, but to answer you question: There is no way to access the youtubeString variable outside the forEach-function, unless you declare it from outside. But then it will only contain the very last value it was set to

Comment: Why is it so hard to understand? I have a forEach action that inserts every `key` value in my `youtubetrailer` scope. If I use my create function inside the forEach it would do the create function for every key value as well. Resulting in multiple copies of a movie in my database. So I'm trying to extract the data from the variable `youtubestring` outside the forEach.

Comment: But the youtubeString-variable will change for each loop, Do you want to have the state of `youtubeString` for every loop or what is it you want? maybe you should do the `var youtubeString = $scope.youtubeTrailer.join()` outside the forEach? And since we don't know how `response` look like it's hard to help, is it an array of theese movie-objects you are talking about?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for my passive aggressive reply earlier. Came across a little harsher then I meant. Declaring the variable outside the forEach fixed everything. If you want you can answer the question so I can upvote you for some rep.

Comment: no worries! Maybe some javascript tutorials regarding function-scope and such would help you in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring the `yourubeString`-variable outside the forEach loop, or even better do the `var youtubeString = $scope.youtubeTrailer.join()` outside the forEach.